# Inverse of a 3x3 matrix error!

Tags: matrices, physics

I have this 3x3 matrix $$E_{ij} = g_{ij} + \bar{\epsilon}_{ijk}z^k$$  and want to derive its inverse. I know that its inverse is given by $$(E^{-1})^{ij} = \frac{1}{1+z^2}(g^{ij} + z^{ij} - \bar{\epsilon}^{ijk}z_k) $$ (and yes, here the k index seems to be following Einstein convention-or what? ).

**i)** One way to find this is to say that the inverse will be a superposition of the symmetric part of $E$ and its anti-symmetric part. So it could be $$(E^{-1})^{ij} = Ag^{ij} + Bz^iz^j + C\bar{\epsilon}^{ijk}z_k$$ and then take the product $E_{ij}(E^{-1})^{jl} = \delta_{i}^{l}$. I am trying to do this but I cannot get enough equations to determine $A,B,C$. Can someone help with this?

**ii)** If I just try to take the first two equations and put them together to make sure they give me the unit matrix I arise to $1+z^2 + \bar{\epsilon}_{ljk}\bar{\epsilon}^{jlm}z^kz_m = 1+z^2$ which gives $$1+z^2 + \delta_{k}^{m}z^kz_m = 1+z^2$$ which is not right. The only other thing worth of mentioning is that $\bar{\epsilon}_{ijk} = \sqrt{\text{det}g} \epsilon_{ijk}$.

I basically care mostly about **i)**. Can someone help me with this calculation?

Update: I think that the inverse given contains a mistake.

Comment: FYI: Yes, there is definetely an implied summation on $k$; you have $i,j$ on the left-hand side, so you must have it on the other.

Comment: This is what I think too. But if you try to calculate the first matrix I am giving $E_{ij}$ times the second $(E^{-1})^{jl}$ where you expect to get $\delta_i^{l}$ it turns out non-sensical. I.e. I end up with something like $0=\bar{\epsilon}_{ijk}\bar{\epsilon}^{jlm}z^kz_m$. But this cannot be zero!

Answer (score 1):

$E_{ij} (E^{-1})^{jk} = (A-Cz^2) \delta_i^k + (B+C)z_iz^k +(A+C) \varepsilon _{ijm}g^{jk} z_m$.

According to the definition, $E_{ij} (E^{-1})_{jk} = \delta_i^k$, so we must have :
$(B+C) = (A+C)=0, (A-Cz^2)=1$, that is the result.

we use $ \varepsilon _{ijk}  \varepsilon ^{ilm} = (\delta^l_j \delta^m_k - \delta^l_k \delta^m_j )$ in the computation.

Comment: Ok, let me think about it. Thanks. You should have the indices up though right? (i.e. $E_{ij}(E^{-1})^{jk}$)

Comment: Sorry I have corrected it.

Comment: And may I ask something else too? If you try to check that indeed the first two matrics I give are inverse to each other. Dont you arrive to some inconsistency?

Comment: Ok, can you break down the first formula you have written because I cannot match up your terms with my terms? In specific I do not understand how you get the middle term $(B+C)z_iz^k$

Comment: Just expand, and notice $B\varepsilon_{ijm} z^jz^kz^m=0$。

Comment: I think you have made a mistake. In the first formula of your answer the A,B,C factors do not add up. If you do the multiplications you must have 2 terms multiplied with A, 2 terms multiplied by B and 2 terms multiplied by C. But in your answer you get 3 times the term C. Sorry, for the confusion.

Comment: I.e. I do not see how you get this $C$ in the middle term. You have already used $C$ in the first and last term correctly.

Comment: $C \varepsilon_{ijm} \varepsilon^{jkl} z^mz_l = C(z^kz_i - \delta_i^k z^2)$, this term corresponds to the first two terms in my expression. Another term comes from $g_{ij} C \varepsilon^{jkl}z_l$